# using the gpu in Python, PATH of nvcc containing spaces cannot be called normally

Tags: python, operating-system, gpu, spacy, nvcc

This is my first question on Stack Overflow.

I am studying text analysis using spacy, but I have a problem using gpu.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program', 'Files\\NVIDIA', 'GPU', 'Computing', 'Toolkit\\CUDA\\v12.1\\bin\\nvcc.EXE', '-gencode=arch=compute_86,code=sm_86', '--ptx', '--std=c++11', '-Ic:\\Users\\este_.MAIN\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\cupy\\_core\\include', '-Ic:\\Users\\este_.MAIN\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\cupy\\_core\\include\\cupy\\_cuda\\cuda-12', '-IC:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v12.1\\include', '-ftz=true', 'C:\\Users\\ESTE_~1.MAI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmptcsy9n4a\\preprocess.cu']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

need to load the NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit, which is an address containing spaces, but it brings up 'C:\Program', 'Files\NVIDIA', 'GPU', 'Computing', 'Toolkit\CUDA\v12.1\bin\nvcc.EXE'.

Even after doing a full reinstall, the same problem occurs.